# Character Array Declaration and initialization

Tags: c

Is the below declaration valid in C?

```
char key[] = {};
```

If not why not?

Comment: How big would the array be?

Comment: I see two completely separate questions above. Suggest picking one.

Comment: I have chosen one and array can be of any size

Comment: What I meant was: after this declaration, how big is the array `key`?

Comment: Have you actually tried it?

Comment: An initializer cannot be empty in C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [online C2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), it is not valid; you may not have an empty initializer list (see 6.7.9, Syntax).  That doesn't mean a specific implementation can't offer an empty initializer list as an extension, but the utility would be unclear.

Beyond that, the compiler has no way of knowing how much storage to set aside for the array.